# split I18n into sperate files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

one of the requirement is to split I18n. I have been looking into the link below in section organization of local files

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

If I look at the `config/locales/en-US.yml` in my project I dont see anything for model, view or controller. I see the data about the items of the webpage. en-US.yml looks like this

```
en-US:
Healthe:
 Points:
   my_points: "Point %{unit}"
   status: "Points achieved"
```

Am I looking at wrong file? How do i split i18n for model, views and controller that has translation?

Answer (score 0):

In this file will be all the translations of the language by default **(en)**. If you need to change the messages then you must first implement an **.yml** file that the community already has prepared in this direction [Locales](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale). Then you have to download the file you need (en-US.yml) and put it in the address **config/locales/en-US.yml** and add or edit the messages you want.
Then you have to edit the configuration of your application and put the one you want (es-ES), for this you have to create a file in **config/initializers/language.rb** and inside

```
Rails.application.config.i18n.default_locale = 'es-US'
```